# Translate linear model to logistic model

Tags: r, regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, regression-coefficients

I have a linear model

Success rate =

0.4019201025 + Match( :X1, -1, -0.14838901625, 1, 0.14838901625, . )
+ Match( :X2, -1, -0.247752255, 1, 0.247752255, . )

I want to translate it into logistic equation.
So that I will able to *find values of coefficients* of this equation (1/(1 + exp(-L(x, β)))

Then I will able to use these coefficients in SAS JMP Simulate Responses as input values with binomial distribution.

Is it possible with R?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have the data, or just the model?

Comment: I have a linear model and I can also generate responses (success rates) for normal distribution based on this model. So I can generate data for all treatment combinations (fractional factorial) where Y will be a response rate.